# Compiling Java Project into Jar file by from command line instead using Maven

Tags: java, maven, project

I am looking into the github project located at,
[SymbolicRegressionInJava](https://github.com/lagodiuk/genetic-programming).  I am familiar compiling java code into jar file but not one huge project using Maven.  I looked into Maven and it is another complex system that need to be figured out.  The bin folder has already a compiled jar file.  I used a command

```
jar -tf symbolic_regression_1.0.jar
```

to see the list of classes used for the project.  It has both gp and ga directories. I added ga (from another github) folder where is gp folder is at ../src/.. Instead of Maven (which I cannot figure it out even with a tutorials), I attempted manually by typing

```
jar cvf test1.jar *
```

It compiled, however, it failed to run like symbolic_regression_1.0.jar.  What I am missing here?

Comment: Maven is like make. This is already a maven project so if you install maven (download, unzip, add to env vars), you can just run from the commandline like the provided instructions on that GH project say.

Comment: I understand that Maven can be a bit overwhelming in the beginning. There's no need to completely understand Maven, the only thing you have to do right now is to install Maven, make sure it's on your path, and type `mvn clean install` in the same directory as where the pom.xml is. This will basically compile and create the jar you need, and will, in the end, make things a little bit easier for you.

Comment: `jar` is **not** a compiler - it's a packer like `zip`. I suppose that you copy file source files (*.java) from `.../src/..`. You have to use `javac` if you want to compile anything

Comment: After installing maven, I used the following commands in maven: git clone https://github.com/lagodiuk/genetic-algorithm.git 
git clone https://github.com/lagodiuk/genetic-programming.git 
mvn -f genetic-algorithm/pom.xml install 
mvn -f genetic-programming/pom.xml install 
It was a long process.  And  I have two folders for genetic algorithm and programming.  But I do not know what maven is doing.  Compiling and Packing?

Comment: the maven processed of genetic-programming has created a new folder called 'target' in it new jar file called gp-1.0. jar so I ran java -jar gp-1.0.jar and I get the error message:no main manifest attribute, in gp-1.0.jar